# On Complete Animation not working :/

Tags: jquery

I have a code that resizes a container div on hover - and I tried to resize a jquery scrollbar inside that container on animation complete - however I broke the whole code and I'm not sure how.

Here's the original:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.scroll-pane').hover(function() {
    $('.leftmofo').animate({
        width: '600px'
        }, 300);

$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:false,dragMaxHeight:
100,wheelSpeed:20}); 

},function() {
    $('.leftmofo').animate({
        width: '256px'
        }, 300);
});



});
```

And here's what I did:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.scroll-pane').animate({width: '600px'}, 300, function() {
    $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:false,dragMaxHeight: 100,wheelSpeed:20});  

},function() {
    $('.leftmofo').animate({
        width: '256px'
        }, 300);
});



});
```

Not sure where I went wrong, any help is appreciated :)))
Thanks :)

Here's a demo of the original:
http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/RmvVc/

Comment: On your original, you have a `hover()`.  On your modified, you do not have a `hover()`.  It's not even clear from your description if removing the `hover()` is what you want.

Comment: pufAmuf!!! Why you deleted "Slide div away halfway - but under a container" ????? I was writing the answer! It was an interesting question! Redo your question if you are still interested! Let me know here!

Comment: Hi I am sorry roXon I actually found the answer in overflow: hidden. Would you still like to respond to my question though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `});` of the first animate call. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.scroll-pane').hover(function() {
     $('.leftmofo').animate({width: '600px'}, 300, function() {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:false,dragMaxHeight: 100,wheelSpeed:20});  
     });
  },function() {
      $('.leftmofo').animate({
        width: '256px'
        }, 300);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.scroll-pane').animate({width: '600px'}, 300, function() {
        $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:false,dragMaxHeight: 100,wheelSpeed:20}); 
    });
    $('.leftmofo').animate({width: '256px'}, 300);
});
```